# Ipad webApp can not show checkbox left line

Tags: html, css, cordova, ipad

env:

```
Ipad web app, use Cordova
```

my html source:

```
<div style="text-align: right; font-size: 15px;">
   <input type="checkbox" disabled>
   space
</div>
```

when my checkbox is disabled, checkbox's left line can not be shown. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think text-align is not suitable for input checkbox.
I resole this bug by delete text-again and use margin-left:

```
<div style="margin-lest: 100px; font-size: 15px;">
   <input type="checkbox" disabled>
   space
</div>
```